# How to create a nested folder-like structure in realm react-native?

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to create a realm database with **items** nested inside **containers**. This would operate like a standard filesystem, where containers can have both items and other containers inside them. How can I create this type of structure? I have set up these schemas:

```
const ItemSchema = {
    name: 'Item',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id:         {type: 'string', indexed: true},
        title:      'string',
        createdAt:  'date',
        updatedAt:  'date',
        picture:    {type: 'data', optional: true},
        parent:     {type: 'Container', optional: true},
    }
};
const ContainerSchema = {
    name: 'Container',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id:         {type:'string', indexed:true},
        title:      'string',
        createdAt:  'date',
        updatedAt:  'date',
        parent:     {type: 'Container', optional: true},
        childContainers: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Container'},
        childItems: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Item'},
    }
};
```

I also set up this model for Items, but haven't created one for Containers yet:

```
class ItemModel {
    constructor(title, children) {
        this.id = Utils.guid();
        this.title = title;
        this.children = children;
        this.createdAt = new Date();
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }
}
```

Now how do I actually populate a database and assign parents and children to existing items? I know I have to do this to create an item:

```
let item = new ItemModel('testItem')
db.write(() => {
            item.updatedAt = new Date();
            db.create('Item', item);
        })
```

But I don't know where I go after that. the realm docs give this example:

```
carList.push({make: 'Honda', model: 'Accord', miles: 100});
```

but once I create a container with `db.create`, how do I then add an existing item as its child (not declare a new item as the docs show)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have created the item you can use `push()` to add it to the list in the container.

Assuming you already have the container, the code could look something like this:

```
let item = new ItemModel('testItem')
db.write(() => {
        item.updatedAt = new Date();
        var item = db.create('Item', item);
        container.childItems.push(item);
    });
```